# Right Triangle calculations returning 0?

Tags: java

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I just wrote a similar code that worked fine. once I got a handle on how to use the scanner class. I am working on a program that takes the height and base of a right triangle and then calculates the perimeter, area, and hypotenuse. But it returns 0.0 for each method and I can't figure out if I am missing some sort of syntax or if I am just really messing up my calculations. Can someone just point me in the right direction of my mistake?

```
    public class RightTriangle {

    private double height;
    private double base;
    private final double hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(base, 2));

   public RightTriangle(double triHeight, double triBase)
   {
       triHeight = height;
       triBase = base;
   }

   public double getPerimeter()
   {
       double perimeter = height + base + hypotenuse;
       return perimeter;
   }

   public double getArea()
   {
       double area = (height + base) / 2;
       return area;
   }

   public double getHypotenuse()
   {
       return hypotenuse;
   }
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class CalculateTriangle 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner triangleHeight = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Triangle Height: ");
        double height = triangleHeight.nextDouble();

        Scanner triangleBase = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Triangle Base: ");
        double base = triangleBase.nextDouble();

        RightTriangle newTriangle = new RightTriangle(height, base);

        newTriangle.getPerimeter();
        double perimeter = newTriangle.getPerimeter();

        newTriangle.getArea();
        double area = newTriangle.getArea();

        newTriangle.getHypotenuse();
        double hypotenuse = newTriangle.getHypotenuse();

        System.out.println(perimeter);
        System.out.println(area);
        System.out.println(hypotenuse);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking `Scanner` out of the picture by just hard-coding the values? That would be my first step (along with converting the main program into unit tests).

Comment: `Scanner` object is needed only once

Comment: Jon Skeet thanks for the tip. I actually need to it take accept input, but I could do it without when testing.

Answer (score 5):

Your code:

```
public RightTriangle(double triHeight, double triBase)
{
   triHeight = height;
   triBase = base;
}
```

Should be:

```
public RightTriangle(double triHeight, double triBase)
{
   height = triHeight;
   base = triBase;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make this as your function-->

```
  private double hypotenuse;

 public double getHypotenuse()
   {
       hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(base, 2));
       return hypotenuse;
   }
```

because you are calculating the value of hypotenuse before you initialize height or base, that is why you are getting 0.

also your constructor should be-->

```
height=triHeight;
bas=triBase;
```

hope this helps.